# new to html, is there a way to make a search box that opens google, or something like it?

Tags: javascript, html

this isn't really for what the title says, but it's a good example of what i would like
i would like to have a text box with text you can enter, i then want that to go in a url that you could click on, or an embed

i tried this to embed an image that can change depending on user input

```
<body>
    <input id="testBox1" type="text" >
    <button onclick=DisplayText()">Display Text</button>
    <p>
    <img src=http://verumignis.com/bitmapgen/<div id="displayText"></div>)alt="Circle Image">
    </p>

    <script>
    function DisplayText() { 
document.getElementById("displayText").innerText = document.getElementById("testBox1").value
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've done it using a tag. All I did was to change the href of the tag to "https://www.google.com/search?q=" and after that the text of the input.
Also, be careful with the typos and the " in your code. It sometimes might cause you some errors.

```js
 function DisplayText(element) {
    let a = document.getElementById("my-link");
    let input = document.getElementById("my-input");
    a.href = "https://www.google.com/search?q=" + input.value; 
}
```

```html
<input id="my-input" type="text">
<button onclick="DisplayText()">See link</button>
<p>
    <div id="displayText"></div>
    <a id="my-link" href="#">Click me!</a>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I made this sample for you. You can make it as your reference.

```js
function DisplayText() { 
   let input = document.getElementById("testBox1");
   let image = document.getElementById("img");
   image.src = 'https://verumignis.com/' + input.value + '.png';
}
```

```css
#img{
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<input id="testBox1" type="text" >
<button onclick="DisplayText()">Display Text</button>
<br><i>Type <b>"logo"</b> in the textfield.</i>
<p>
   <!-- <img src=http://verumignis.com/bitmapgen/<div id="displayText"></div>)alt="Circle Image"> -->
   <img src="https://static.thenounproject.com/png/1372075-200.png" id="img" alt="Circle Image">
</p>
```

Comment: for some reason this doesn't seem to work in google sites

Comment: or anywhere else, it only works on _this_ website

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not sure what you want you achieve. Do you mean if your type any words in the textfield and it match any google image, it will embed in your ```Circle Image``` image?

Comment: ill tell you what happens, it says "`function DisplayText() { let input = document.getElementById("testBox1"); let image = document.getElementById("img"); image.src = 'https://verumignis.com/' + input.value + '.png'; } #img{ width: 100px; height: 100px; } `" and then shows what it's supposed to, however it doesn't work

Comment: Can you show an draft/image of the final output you want to achive once you type on the ```textfield``` and click this ```button``` *Display Text*?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1hTHpw2AIohSloJOsy2SxBW6DlFyVxvYo?usp=sharing this has 2 pictures, 1. how your code works outside of stack overflow and 2. a mockup of what i want

Comment: the mockup code `<body>
    <input id="testBox1" type="text" >
    <button onclick="DisplayText()">Display Text</button>
<p></p>
    <img src="http://verumignis.com/bitmapgen/0000000000000000-0000000000000000-0000000000000000-0000000000000000-0000000000000000-0000011111000000-0001111111110000-0011111111111000-0011111111111000-0011111111111000-0001111111110000-0000011111000000-0000000000000000-0000000000000000-0000000000000000-0000000000000000" alt="Circle Image">
`

Comment: also, i use linux however i don't think that _should_ matter

Comment: You need to move the function **inside the ```<script>``` tag**.

Comment: Also the image *"mockup of what i want"* show already an image even there's no inputted on the textfield.

Comment: Yeah, I just made it like that to show what it _should_ look like, none of the code _really_ works

Comment: I'm sorry that I couldn't help. But the question is **unclear**. Can you make an draft of *before* and *after* of you work? a playground should best.